# InAppBillingPlugin con Xamarin me da error en modo release, a alguien le ha pasado?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play

Hola estoy utilizando xamarin form y InAppBillingPlugin para obtener suscripciones dentro de la aplicación todo funciona bien pero al momento que quiero general mi apk en modo release me marca el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, me estoy basando en esta documentación: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/TestingAndTroubleshooting.html